# WebRTC using Peerjs with Native Android/iOS clients

Tags: android, ios, node.js, webrtc, peerjs

We're trying to build an internal system which will provide us with simple chat/video features using WebRTC. We have successfully deployed Peer.js client and server which works great over the browser.

However, we can't seem to find a fairly simple Android/iOS client/SDK to make it compatible with our PeerJS server.

We've tried looking into [AppRTC](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc/) and got the Android client running with their server, however we can't understand how to connect it to our PeerJS server since that Android client (and server implementation) seems really complicated (we're not JAVA experts).

I've also looked into EasyRTC, however it seems that they've pulled back their native SDKs, but the technology stack looks really close to ours.

My question is, has anyone got and Android/iOS Client working with WebRTC running on a NodeJS server? What are the possible workarounds to get this up and running natively on Android?

We're looking for a fairly simple Android SDK (links to libraries/sample projects) which could work with a PeerJS server.

Edit: We could build a signaling server (on NodeJS) ourselves, but how can we build the Android/iOS clients from then on?

I'm offering a bounty of 200 rep to whoever can answer our questions.

Comment: I know this is a old topic, but I'm facing the same situation here. Did you find anything about it or even get this working?

Comment: @ErickGallani Yeah we did, we moved from peerjs to a simple [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) implementation and our iOS/Android devs did their magic and modified the Android/iOS SDKs to make it work somehow. Not sure how though :/

Comment: I'm using peerjs on android webView with javascript interface for voice and video calls. It works with the following limitations, 1. Unlike a BG service, the activity which hosts the webView may get destroyed when user opens other apps. 2. PeerJS has issues with NAT traversal even if you use a TURN server.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PeerJS but it seems like using websockets. If that's the case you have to implement WebSocket client functionality in you native clients (and various PeerJS internal connection/signaling protocol).

For native to native signaling, it's really simple because we only have to exchange SDP and ICE candidate messages between clients (via WebSocket or any other messaging mechanisms).

To connect to PeerJS server, obviously, we need PeerJS client implemented in Java or C(ObjC).

I'll be surprised if such implementation or SDK exists.

I don't know current state of AppRTC source, but in its old version, it hosted a WebView to run a kind of HTML+JavaScript signaling client.

That is, you can host a WebView and reuse your PeerJS client in Android/iOS apps.

Comment: That makes sense. We could potentially build our own websocket server, but we're not too sure about the Android/iOS clients. Any tutorials out there that we could use, to build a signaling server (on NodeJS) and Android/iOS clients from scratch?

Comment: @Ignas I did searched tutorials or open sources but most are too big or too complicated for my simple purpose. So I made a simple signaling server in 1 day with J2EE. Basic chat example is enough (https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/chat_sever_using_websocket_totd), except don't send the message back to the sender. With this server, connect 2 clients, one send offer the other reply answer. That's all. Calling sequence: http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/native-apis

Answer (score 1):

You can have look at Crosswalk project. By follow [Tutorial: porting Android app from Web App for WebRTC using PeerJS library](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/webrtc.html). I have done it and it worked perfectly.

There are another option which is using http://phonegap.com/ to port from web app to Android/iOS but I could not make it work event just with "getUserMedia" API.

Hope this help

Comment: I'm afraid it's not an option. It had to be native so we used AppRTC as our base.

Comment: In case you want to have "really" native app, I think you can have look at the official website of WebRTC: http://www.webrtc.org/native-code or you can check an open-source project OpenWebRTC: http://www.openwebrtc.io/ They provide API to build native WebRTC application on many platform such as: iOS/ Android/ MacOS/ Linux.
Hope this help!

Comment: Yeah, that's what we did, though it took us a while to sort it out. Cheers for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a example in here https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685276/how-do-record-media-stream-data-as-h-264mp4-in-webrtc-android)

On the server they used nodejs + socket.io + AngurlarJs.
On the client they used libjingle_peerconnection + socket.io Client.