# How do record media stream data as h.264(mp4) in webRTC android?

Tags: android, webrtc, libjingle

Please help me!
I used this example in https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC to streaming video and audio from a android device to an other android device.In this example, they used 2 librarys is : libjingle_peerConnection and SocketIo client but i don't know how to save streaming data as h.264 format?

Comment: Have any idea? Please help....

Comment: As far as I know, you can not do that.

Comment: I found a solution for this. Thanks

Comment: @ĐặngHuyHoàng Hi Could you please share your solution here.

Comment: hi. i work on a project like this. and i should save streaming data how can i do this? i search all net but cant find any things. did you solve this? can you help me. is very importance for me. i hope you help me. thanks.